# OpenGL ES 2.0 works only once

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm successfully drawing simple shapes on my `GLSurfaceView` using OpenGL ES 2.0. So far i'm not using any textures. The problem is that when i re-run for the second time the activity with `GLSurfaceView` the screen is empty (black), shapes are not being drawn again. I have to reinstall the whole app to make it work again.
I don't have any special methods `onPause` & `onResume` so i assume the new instance of `GLSurfaceView` should redraw the screen each time i re-run the application.

Does anyone have any clue what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't have any special methods `onPause` & `onResume`

That's likely your problem. You need to follow the [documentation of GLSurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html), specifically what it says under "Activity Life-cycle":

> A GLSurfaceView must be notified when the activity is paused and resumed. GLSurfaceView clients are required to call onPause() when the activity pauses and onResume() when the activity resumes. These calls allow GLSurfaceView to pause and resume the rendering thread, and also allow GLSurfaceView to release and recreate the OpenGL display.

Comment: Eh... I overrode both methods and left them empty... apologies for taking your time. Issie fixed.